# how to check if the value of a column exists in list value of another column in sql hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have the table A as below:

| id | november_product | december_product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | A,C,D |
| 123 | B | A,C,D |
| 456 | C | E,F,G |

December_product is list values, Each value separated by commas. I want to check if value of 'November_product' column esists in 'December_product' column and show value of 'november product' not exists in 'december_product'?

Expected result:

| id | november_product | december_product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | B | A,C,D |
| 456 | C | E,F,G |

Comment: Normalize your tables. It'll be better for you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM  A
WHERE CHARINDEX(november_product, december_product) > 0
```